# Digital Modulation

Tags: digital-modulation

Hey I have an exam tomorrow and I cant work out this past question and I would appreciate any help.

A black and white TV picture consists of approx. 3x10^5 elements, each of which may occupy one of 16 distinct brightness levels with equal probability. Assume the rate of transmission is 30 frames/s and the signal to noise ratio is 30dB.

Using the information capacity law, calculate the minimum bandwidth required to support the transmission of the resulting video signal

Comment: What have you figured out yourself for far?  (As an aside, it's 1st week of September.  Where on Earth would you have exams at this time of year?)

Comment: In Ireland! I know the channel capacity law is C=Blog2(1+ S/N). So I need to find the capacity but I cant figure out to find it without already knowing the bandwidth using the formulae from my lecture notes. I reckon I am missing some notes from the class.

Comment: You're asking us to do your homework for you? Really? How do you learn anything that way? How will you support yourself if you don't know how to do this stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the formula to get the bandwidth needed in terms of the data rate and SNR:

$$B = \frac{C}{\log{}_2\left(1+\mathrm{SNR}\right)}$$

You've been told enough to work out how much information each image frames contains, and how many frames are transmitted per second, you can work out the data rate.

Note, however, that using this result is not really practical. The Shannon-Hartely formula tells us *in principle* that it's possible to carry a certain amount of data over a channel with a given bandwidth and SNR. But it tells us nothing about what coding scheme might allow us to do so. And in practice, real encoding schemes only approach the Shannon capacity asymptotically, so a real system will need slightly more bandwidth than what's given by the formula.

Comment: Thank you I just figured it out there I was making it out to be more difficult than it is! I appreciate the extra theory too.